# How to setup wikitude7.1.0sdk on android studio

Tags: android-studio, wikitude-sdk

I try to run wikitude-7.1.0sdk-example with android studio on windows. But when I connect real phone to debug it, there has report some error.Like follow:
Error:error: E:/WikitudeSDK_NativeAPI_Android/Examples/NativeSDKExamples/plugins/src/main/cpp/jni/../lib/x86/libippicv.a(jmp_icvippiMirror_8u_C3IR_as.s.o): relocation R_386_GOTOFF against preemptible symbol icv_ippJumpIndexForMergedLibs cannot be used when making a shared object
.....

I have try to run wikitude-5.0.0sdk-example, it work.
There has some difference between 7.1.0sdk file and 5.0.0 sdk file.[5.0.0sdk-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiJ96.jpg)     [7.1.0sdk-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76una.jpg)

I think there maybe something wrong in plugins. I try to remove this file directly. Apparently It doesn't work.

Does anyone have any solutions? 
thanks for your help, best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

I have fond some incomplete answer on wikitude forum. I just delete the dependencies about plugins in app build.gradle.

In this way I can't use the features in plugins. But it does not matter to me.
So, now I can run sdk example.